# Regex in Objective-c not working as intended

Tags: objective-c, regex, xcode, unit-testing, nsregularexpression

I use Regex for checking a password. But it is not working as intended.
I use some Unit-tests to check the regex.

```
@implementation NSString (regexMatch)

- (BOOL)matchesRegex:(NSString *)regexPattern
{
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression
                                  regularExpressionWithPattern:regexPattern 
                                  options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                  error:&error];

    if(error) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Error on maches regex: %@ on %@: %@", regex, self, error);
        return NO;
    }

    NSUInteger maches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:self 
                                               options:NSRegularExpressionSearch 
                                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, [self length])];

    return (maches > 0);
}

@end
```

The Regex:

```
const static NSString *REGEX_VALID_PASS = @"(^((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[-_,.@#$%'\"]).{6,20})$)";
```

Unit tests:

```
//Password 
// At least:
//  - between 6 and 20 chars
//  - a capital character
//  - a small character
//  - a digit
//  - a special char: - _ , . @ # $ % ´ '
STAssertTrue([@"Pass1-" matchesRegex:REGEX_VALID_PASS], @"Password 1 failed");

STAssertTrue([@"aPrettyLongPassw0rd@" matchesRegex:REGEX_VALID_PASS], @"Password 2 failed");

STAssertTrue([@"Pw987321-_,.@#$%'`" matchesRegex:REGEX_VALID_PASS], @"Password 3 failed");

//Returns TRUE ???
STAssertFalse([@"password1@" matchesRegex:REGEX_VALID_PASS], @"Wrong password 4 works (No capital letter)");

//Returns TRUE ???
STAssertFalse([@"PASSWORD2#" matchesRegex:REGEX_VALID_PASS], @"Wrong password 5 works (No small letter)");

STAssertFalse([@"Password8" matchesRegex:REGEX_VALID_PASS], @"Wrong password 6 works (No special letter)");

STAssertFalse([@"Password$" matchesRegex:REGEX_VALID_PASS], @"Wrong password 7 works (No digit letter)");

STAssertFalse([@"PrettyLongPasswordIsWrong123#" matchesRegex:REGEX_VALID_PASS], @"Wrong password 8 works (> 20)");

STAssertFalse([@"Pw@3" matchesRegex:REGEX_VALID_PASS], @"Wrong password 9 works (< 6)");
```

Password 'password1@' and 'PASSWORD2#' are returning TRUE but there are not correct.

Errors:

```
file://localhost/Users/user/app/AppTest.m: error: testRegex (AppTest) failed: "[@"password1@" matchesRegex:REGEX_VALID_PASS]" should be false. Wrong password 4 works (No capital letter)

and


file://localhost/Users/user/app/AppTest.m: error: testRegex (AppTest) failed: "[@"PASSWORD2#" matchesRegex:REGEX_VALID_PASS]" should be false. Wrong password 5 works (No small letter)
```

Comment: Besides from your problem, you can remove some brackets, `^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[-_,.@#$%'\"]).{6,20}$` would do the same.

Comment: Thanks, I know. I copied it from the server-side. I first wanted to get it working before I altered the Regex. But thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specified `NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive` option, so it makes sense that the expression does not differentiate between upper and lower case letters.

With the `NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive` option specified, `(?=.*[a-z])` will match any letter, including capital ones; similarly, `(?=.*[A-Z])` will match lowercase letters as well.

Your failed unit tests expect a different behavior: both of them are checking that the password contains upper and lower case letters, while the input contains letters in the same case.

Comment: Ah, that was pretty simple. Thank you. Changed it to NSRegularExpressionSearch